# java.lang.IllegalStateException MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

In my application I use a VideoView where playing a MediaPlayer, and in some cases has released me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:350)
at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:256)
at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:239)
at com.wul4.paythunder.hologram.MainActivity.cargarVideo(MainActivity.java:261)
at com.wul4.paythunder.hologram.MainActivity$6.run(MainActivity.java:395)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My function to load the video I start it is:

```
public static void cargarVideo(final String video){

    Uri path = Uri.parse(video);

    Video.setVideoURI(path);

    if(video.contains(NetworkUtils.nombreVideo(prefs.getString("listen",""))) ||
            video.contains(NetworkUtils.nombreVideo(prefs.getString("talk","")))) {
        Video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.e("####", "onPrepared");
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
    Video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                Log.e("####", "onCompletion");

                cargarVideo(video);

            }
        });
    }


    Video.start();

}
```

This error does not know to be, so if someone knows or has occurred and you can lie down for a hand, he would appreciate it.

A greeting and thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I searched and read that the solution may lie in the method call `setOnPreparedListener` including within the function `onPrepared` the video initialization --> `mp.start()`

I tried it and now the same behavior seems, do not know if in the future again give the same error

Comment: No, in this case been in a "OnePlus - A0001"

Comment: you should call video.start() inside setOnPreparedListener

Comment: @Meenaxi I tried it and has not been solved, putting it in the method `setOnPreparedListened`
When it appears the error is on the line
`Uri path = Uri.parse(video);`
so I'm thinking to use the function `setVideoPath(path);` intead of `setVideoURI(path);` to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to take a look at the Life Cycle of a MediaPlayer Instance?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Basically from what I see, you did not properly 'reset' the MediaPlayer object so that it can properly rerun again.

Try having MediaPlayer.reset()  and see if it works.

```
@Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                Log.e("####", "onCompletion");

                // Reset the player here

                cargarVideo(video);

            }
```